# SignalR Chat: Differentiating ListItem sender and receiver for Css

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr, chat

I'm building a small ChatHub application based on the Microsoft-Tutorial for SignalR and JavaScript.

In short: hub-messages are put in a created-on-demand (li)

For styling purposes I'm looking to add a classname to these (li), differentiating them into categories "sender" and "receiver"

Background: 
Each Side of the ChatConnection has a different view. I'm still building on the logic of the texting, so this is far from flawless.

My dbo for friendstable is UserFriends, depending on which side of the friendship you are, you get a different (but mirrored) chatwindow.

Cshtml-snippet:

```
     @foreach (var item in Model.UserFriends)
        {
            @if (item.FriendChatName == @User.Identity.Name)
            {

                <div>
                    <button class="open-button" onclick="openChatForm()">@item.UserChatName</button>
                    <div class="chat-popup" id="myChatForm" style="display:none">
                        <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container">
                            <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeChatForm()">@item.UserChatName</button>
                           <input type="hidden" id="receiverInput" value="@item.UserChatName"/>
                                <ul id="messagesList" class="chatmessage receiver" ></ul>


                            <input type="hidden" id="userInput" class="receiverInput" value="@item.FriendChatName" />
                            <textarea placeholder="Type message.." required style="height:32px;" id="messageInput"></textarea>
                            <button type="submit" asp-route-user="@User.Identity.Name" asp-route-sender="@User.Identity.Name" asp-route-receiver="@item.UserChatName" class="btn" id="sendButton">Send</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>


            }
            @if (item.UserChatName == @User.Identity.Name)
            {
                <div>
                    <button class="open-button" onclick="openChatForm()">@item.FriendChatName</button>
                    <div class="chat-popup" id="myChatForm" style="display:none">
                        <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container">
                            <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeChatForm()">@item.FriendChatName</button>
                            <input type="hidden" id="receiverInput" value="@item.FriendChatName" />
                            <ul id="messagesList" class="chatmessage sender" ></ul>

                            <input type="hidden" id="userInput" value="@item.UserChatName" />
                            <textarea placeholder="Type message.." required style="height:32px;" id="messageInput"></textarea>
                            <button type="submit" asp-area="" asp-route-user="@User.Identity.Name" asp-route-sender="@User.Identity.Name" asp-route-receiver="@item.FriendChatName" class="btn" id="sendButton">Send</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        }
```

the ChatHub Class:

```
       public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
}
```

and the chat.js script-snippet:

```
    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();
     connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
var encodedMsg = user + ": " + msg;
var li = document.createElement("li");    
li.textContent = encodedMsg;    
document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
    });
    connection.start().catch(function (err) {
return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;


connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});
event.preventDefault();
    });
```

I'm trying to get this kind of thing:

```
        if (user == reciever  ) {
    li.className = "receiver";
}
if (user == sender) {
    li.className = "sender";
}
```

With the help of this snippet

```
    var sender = document.getElementById("senderInput").value;
var receiver = document.getElementById("receiverInput").value;
```

But when all smoothed out i get nothing but a runtime error

[image: Error]

this is the view in two browser windows

[image: ChatView in two browser windows]

Anybody can help me with the building of the If in the chat.Js or has other structural notes on how i would go about styling sendermessenges and receivermessages differently, would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm back to post my solution for this problem:

```
     @foreach (var item in Model.User.Friends)
            {
                <li>
                    <button class="open-button" onclick="openChatForm(event, '@item.Id@@ChatForm')" type="button" style="max-width:200px;">@item.UserName</button>
                    <div class="chat-popup" id="@item.Id@@ChatForm" style="display:none; width:300px; margin-left:900px;">
                        <div>
                            <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container" style="position:absolute">
                                <button class="btn cancel" onclick="closeChatForm(event, '@item.Id@@ChatForm')" type="button">@item.FirstName</button>
                                <input type="hidden" id="receiverInput" value="@item.UserName" />
                                <ul id="messagesList" class="chatmessage" style="max-height:600px;"></ul>
                                <input type="hidden" id="senderInput" value="@User.Identity.Name" />
                                <textarea placeholder="Type message.." required style="height:32px;" id="messageInput"></textarea>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn" id="sendButton">Send</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <script>

                    </script>

                </li>
            }
```

this is the chat.js

```
    connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
var encodedMsg = user + ": " + msg;

var li = document.createElement("li");
li.className += user;

var senderForSenderForm = document.getElementById("senderInput").value;
var senderForReceiverForm = document.getElementById("receiverInput").value;
var receiverForSenderForm = document.getElementById("receiverInput").value;
var receiverForReceiverForm = document.getElementById("senderInput").value;

if (senderForSenderForm === li.className ) {
    li.className += " toRight";
}
if (receiverForSenderForm === li.className) {
    li.className += " toLeft";
}
if (senderForReceiverForm === li.className ) {
    li.className += " toRight";
}
if (receiverForReceiverForm === li.className) {
 li.className += " toLeft";
}

li.textContent = encodedMsg;
document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);

    });

    connection.start().catch(function (err) {
return console.error(err.toString());
    });

    document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
var user = document.getElementById("senderInput").value;
var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});
event.preventDefault();
    });
```

ChatHub is still the same..

In short i refactored the chatwindow to one scope,
generated (li)'s for messages and adding a class to it to finally base the styling off this className.

Styling for all friends is Okay, Chatting atm is just possible with one friend, will update when fixed!

[image: dogFaceChat]